# ArrayOutofBoundsException - Attempting to read to/from file into Hash Map

Tags: java

I'm working on a homework assignment and have run into an odd "ArrayOutOfBoundsException" error - I know what the error means (essentially I'm trying to reference a location in an array that isn't there) but I'm not sure why it's throwing that error? I'm not sure what I'm missing, but obviously there must be some logic error somewhere that I'm not seeing.

**PhoneDirectory.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.io.*;

class PhoneDirectory {
    private HashMap<String, String> directoryMap;
    File directory;
    public PhoneDirectory() { //create file for phone-directory
        directory = new File("phone-directory.txt");
        directoryMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        try(BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(directory))) {
            String currentLine;
            while((currentLine = buffer.readLine()) != null) { //set currentLine = buffer.readLine() and check if not null
                String[] fileData = currentLine.split(","); //create array of values in text file - split by comma
                directoryMap.put(fileData[0], fileData[1]); //add item to directoryMap
            }
        }
        catch(IOException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public PhoneDirectory(String phoneDirectoryFile) {
        directory = new File(phoneDirectoryFile);
        directoryMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        try(BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(directory))) {
            String currentLine;
            while((currentLine = buffer.readLine()) != null) { //set currentLine = buffer.readLine() and check if not null
                String[] fileData = currentLine.split(","); //create array of values in text file - split by comma
                directoryMap.put(fileData[0], fileData[1]); //add item to directoryMap
            }
        }
        catch(IOException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public String Lookup(String personName) {
        if(directoryMap.containsKey(personName))
            return directoryMap.get(personName);
        else
            return "This person is not in the directory.";
    }
    public void AddOrChangeEntry(String name, String phoneNumber) {
        //ASK IF "IF-ELSE" CHECK IS NECESSARY
        if(directoryMap.containsKey(name))
            directoryMap.put(name,phoneNumber); //if name is a key, update listing
        else
            directoryMap.put(name, phoneNumber); //otherwise - create new entry with name
    }
    public void DeleteEntry(String name) {
        if(directoryMap.containsKey(name))
            directoryMap.remove(name);
        else
            System.out.println("The person you are looking for is not in this directory.");
    }
    public void Write() {
        try(BufferedWriter writeDestination = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(directory)))
        {
            for(String key : directoryMap.keySet())
            {
                writeDestination.write(key + ", " + directoryMap.get(key) + '\n');
                writeDestination.newLine();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Driver.java**

```
public class Driver {
    PhoneDirectory list1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PhoneDirectory list1 = new PhoneDirectory("test.txt");
        list1.AddOrChangeEntry("Disney World","123-456-7890");
        list1.Write();
    }

}
```

Essentially I'm creating a file called "test.txt" and adding the line "Disney World, 123-456-7890" - what's weird is that the code still works - but it throws me that error anyway, so what's really happening? (For the record, I'm referring to the line(s): directoryMap.put(fileData[0], fileData[1]) - which would be line 14 and 28 respectively.)

Comment: Odds are, one of your lines doesn't have a `,` (empty line somewhere mb), so fileData[1] doesn't exist, leading to an error.

Comment: Which line causes the exception?

Comment: @pbabcdefp in the Driver, it says the error is caused by line 4 - but it continues running the rest of the code fine (as the file is created, and the line is properly added)

Comment: You can replace your first constructor with `this("phone-directory.txt");`

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard I was thinking that too, but I checked, and there's commas in both lines, so that can't be it. I *did* put a space between the comma and phone number, so maybe that's why?

Comment: Time to learn debugging my friend!

Comment: @pbabcdefp That actually helped - I noticed that the array decreased in size - went to check the file - and there was apparently a blank line in the file (probably from when I messed with it earlier) which it was trying to read - and got an error (obviously because there was no "," split).

Problem solved!

Comment: Glad I could help. I agree with @m0skit0 though. Learning to use a debugger will save you hours. Loads of `println` statements all over the place is not the way to do debugging.

Comment: And with current tools it's easier and faster.